# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ..., but this dictionary requires ...

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The whole Error Message:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
'MyClass`2[Implementation1,Implementation2]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'MyClass`2[Interface1,Interface2]'.
```

In my View, I have the model declaration:

```
@model MyClass<Interface1, Interface2>
```

Where MyClass is a Class and Interface1 and Interface2 are interfaces

on my Controller Action I am calling:

```
return View(model);
```

where:
**model** is of type...

```
MyClass<Implementation1,Implementation2>
```

...and **Implementation1** implements **Interface1** and **Implementation2** implements **Interface2**

Is there any way to avoid this error, without having to declare my model as below?

```
@model MyClass<Implementation1, Implementation2>
```

Comment: Any reason you can't make your model use `MyClass<Interface1, Interface2>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `MyClass` is **invariant** you can not do this, that means `MyClass<Implementation1, Implementation2>` is not `MyClass<Interface1, Interface2>`, hence the error.

As it's not an interface or  a delegate, the class cannot to be declared as **covariant**. Although you can create an interface and make it covariant using [out keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx):

```
public interface IMyClass<out T1, out T2>
{
    ...
}

public class MyClass<T1, T2> : IMyClass<T1, T2>
{
    ...
}
```

The model declaration in the View:

```
@model IMyClass<Interface1, Interface2>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
It seems I have a design problem at all. `Interface1` and `Interface2` are types of properties on `MyClass` I would like to use on my view. And I can declare them in `IMyClass` only if they are read-only, so htey will not be serializable!

Comment: @LeopoldoWagner, this is getting beyond the scope of the original question. Post another question and SO community will be glad to help.